# CSS tooltip arrow is not working

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have been trying to make one tooltip. Something like in the below image which appears when I hover on image:

[image: Tooltip]

Problem is the below triangle arrow is not coming at all. I have googled it a lot and went through previously asked stackoverflow question. But no luck. I am going to put code below, could you please let me know where I am going wrong:

HTML code:

```
<span class="help-tooltip" tooltip-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
             adipiscing elit. Donec non diam enim. Quisque leo erat, vulputate id mi  et, pharetra vulputate sapien.">

            <img src="/static/img/help.png">
 </span>
```

Below is my css code:

```
span[tooltip-text]:hover:after {
    content: attr(tooltip-text);
    padding: 8px 8px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    bottom: 120%;
    width: 275px;
    height: auto;
    background: #0679ca;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.help-tooltip:hover {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this to achieve your goal,

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 50px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">

<div class="tooltip">Hover me
 <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```